# Prevent signalr idle timeout

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm using signalr in c# web application and do some logic in signalr on disconnected event this event called for idle timeout also i want to prevent that logic from idle timeout

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.